# how to list fonts installed from Chrome extension

Tags: flash, google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-extension, typeerror

I'm looking for a way to get the list of fonts installed on a computer from a chrome extension. I found no function like EnumerateAllFonts({}) from Firefox in chrome and when I tried to embed a swf object as I would do in a html page, there was no result except the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getDeviceFonts' ... (bug related to some security stuff I assume...)

Would someone give me some tips, I would be really grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tested your Flash-based `getDeviceFonts` method on a normal web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in fact I found the function I wanted... - .-"
I didn't read the documentation carefully enough.
So, for those who wonder how to do it, the function is named `chrome.fontSettings.getFontList(function callback)`

And here is the related page : [fontSettings documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/fontSettings.html)